# Code completion in Pycharm is not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, pycharm, boto3

While using boto3 client, PyCharm autocompletion is not giving complete list of methods. I have gone through several posts regarding similar issues, but nothing worked out so far. Can anyone suggest a solution here? Attaching a screenshot for reference.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
**If code completion doesn't work, this may be due to one of the following reasons:**

1.The Power Save Mode is on (File | Power Save Mode). Turning it on minimizes power consumption of your laptop by eliminating the background operations, including error highlighting, on-the-fly inspections, and code completion.

2.Your file doesn't reside in a content root , so it doesn't get the required class definitions and resources needed for code completion.

3.Refer to Configuring Project Structure for more details.

4.A file containing classes and functions that you want to appear in completion suggestions list is marked as a plain text file.

5.External libraries that contain functions that you want to appear in the completion suggestions list are not added as dependencies or global libraries.
```

I hope this solves your Problem.